Coframe on coset space using Maurer-Cartan form
Suppose $G$ is a Lie group and $H$ is a Lie subgroup. Then, consider the principal $H$-bundle, $\pi:G\longrightarrow G/H$ where $G/H$ is coset manifold and $\pi$ is the canonical projection. Then, we can write the Lie algebra of $G$ as the direct sum
\begin{equation}
\mathfrak{g}=\mathfrak{h} \oplus \mathfrak{k}
\end{equation} where $\mathfrak{h}$ is the Lie algebra of $H$ considered as Lie subalgebra of $\mathfrak{g}$ and $\mathfrak{k}$ is the rest.
Let $\mathfrak{h}=span\{H_I\}$ and $\mathfrak{k}=span\{K_A\}$. Suppose $\Theta$ is the Maurer-Cartan form on $G$. Then we can write
\begin{equation}
\Theta=w^IH_I + e^AK_A
\end{equation} where of course $w^I$ and $e^A$'s are one forms on $G$.
Now, say $L:U \longrightarrow \pi^{-1}(U)$ is a local section, i.e, $U \circ L = Id_U$ on a open subset $U \subseteq G/H$ and consider the pullback of $e^A$ under $L$, namely,
\begin{equation}
e^A_{(L)} \equiv L^* e^A
\end{equation} which is now a one form on $U$.
Now, I try to show that $e^A_{(L)}$'s are linearly independent. That is, if we have some $\lambda_A\in \mathbf{R}$ such that
\begin{equation}
\lambda_A e^A_{(L)} =0 \ \ \text{summation convention is employed}
\end{equation} then one has
\begin{equation}
\lambda_A =0 \ \ \text{for any} \ A=1,..,dim\mathfrak{k}.
\end{equation}
Here is my attempt, let $p\in U$ and $0 \neq X\in T_pG/H$ then I was able to show that $dL_p(X)$ is not vertical so that it has horizontal part. Thus,
\begin{equation}
dL_p(X)=vertical+\alpha^A(K_A^\#)_{L(p)}
\end{equation} where $K_A^\#$ is the left invariant vector field on $G$ obtained by $K_A \in \mathfrak{k}\subseteq \mathfrak{g}.$ Then,
\begin{equation}
(e^B_{(L)})_{p}(X)=(e^B)_{L(p)}(dL_p(X))=\alpha^A(e^B)_{L(p)}((K_A^\#)_{L(p)})=\alpha^A\delta^B_A=\alpha^B.
\end{equation}
Therefore,
\begin{equation}
0=\lambda_B(e^B_{(L)})_{p}(X)=\sum_B\lambda_B\alpha^B
\end{equation} from which one should conclude that $\lambda_B=0$ for any $B$ but I cannot find an argument for this last step.
Thanks in advance.

Let me first point out that the decomposition $\mathfrak g=\mathfrak h\oplus\mathfrak k$ that you use is not canonical at all, you have to choose a complementary subspace $\mathfrak k$. (And it makes a lot of difference for further developments whether $\mathfrak k$ can be chosen to be invariant under the adjoint action of $H$.)
The way you are trying to prove linear independence is a rather tedious one. Basically, an argument is contained in what you are writing. You say that "$dL_p(X)$ is not vertical" without saying exactly what this means. You can  read this as "If $dL_p(X)$ is vertical, then $X=0$". But  $dL_p(X)$ is vertical if and only if $0=e^A(dL_p(X))=L^*e^A(p)(X)$. This means that the map from the tangent space of $G/H$ at $P$ to $\mathbb R^k$, where $k=\dim(\mathfrak k)=\dim(G/H)$ is injective and then it is a fact from linear algebra that the maps $L^*e^A(p)$ have to be linearly independent.
The argument for this is as follows: Since the two spaces have the same dimension, the map is also surjective. But if $\lambda_AL^*e^A(p)=0$ the values of the map would be contained in the subspace where $\lambda_Ax^A=0$, which thus is only possible if all $\lambda^A=0$ for all $A$.

You mean the two arguments that I wrote already show that the kernel is trivial, and the rest follows from the equality of dimensions. I think I get it. Thanks a lot for the clear explanation.
